# Can Power Query differentiate between domains and apps?

Tags: powerquery

I have a column that could be either domains or apps, for example:

| Domain/App |
| --- |
| com.stackexchange.stackoverflow |
| 356110207 |
| stackoverflow.com |

Can you have an automated **Type** column that will determine - by the "address" alone - which type is it?

| Domain/App | Type |
| --- | --- |
| com.stackexchange.stackoverflow | App |
| 356110207 | App |
| stackoverflow.com | Domain |

Comment: are you trying to look up the values in a column against a table?

Comment: No, just whether its "address" looks like that of a domain vs that of an app.

Comment: And when does an address look like either one of those ? What is the rule

Comment: I was hoping for a smart function that knows...